# Mac Catalyst: UIApplicationDelegate.applicationDidBecomeActive called only once. How then to keep Data Models up to date?

Tags: mac-catalyst

Same thing in `UIScene` based environment. The `UISceneDelegate.sceneDidBecomeActive` called only once.

How then to keep Data Models up to date? What can be used as a replacement for `UIApplicationDelegate.applicationDidBecomeActive`?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score -1):

You can add the following observer instead:

```
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(self.applicationWillBecomeActive(_:)), name: UIApplication.didBecomeActiveNotification, object: nil)
```